# Conditional menu display

Tags: menus, conditional-tags, frontpage

I have the line of code below with the intention to display the called menu in every other page except the home page but it still shows up on the home page. Any ideas what the problem could be.

```
    <?php if (!is_home()) {
    wp_nav_menu (array('menu'=>'sideBar','menu_class' => 'navbar')); 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your home page blog index or static page?

[`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) is meant to check if we are on blog index (latest posts), while [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) checks if home is static page set in *Settings > Reading*.

Comment: The home page is Static.

Comment: I guess you should be using the `is_front_page()` conditional tag then.